# How can I resolve "cannot resolve symbol 'R'" in Android Studio 4.1 relating to a com.google.android.material resource ID?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 4.1. Now every so often, AS decides that it doesn't know what 'R' is, and in particular only on a specific resource ID: `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`

I think I remember reading somewhere that these resource IDs have been changed to no longer be declared 'final', but I'm not clear on why or if this would cause this problem.

Invalidating cache and restart "fixes" this for a while, but then it comes back. All types of clean, rebuild project, etc. have no effect.

I am using this resource to dynamically get the TextView associated with the Snackbar in order to change the gravity of where it shows onscreen, but only in certain cases (i.e. I don't want to change the gravity in the XML definition).

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Have you tried syncing files? Tools -> Sync Project with Gradle files

Comment: I am having exact issue, have you found any solution yet?

Comment: Since I tried Eneko's suggestion of Sync the project with Gradle Files, it has not yet showed up again. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Well, its back again, slightly differently: I updated to AS 4.1.1, and the associated Gradle plugin et al and now I am seeing red on not only the same snackbar_text resource ID but also on use of a system service (VIBRATOR_SERVICE). The permission for this has been in my manifest for ages. I did the suggested Alt-shift-enter to "fix" it, and it put a second permission statement in the manifest! (which did make the red squiggles go away).

Answer (score 5):

Try using only `R.id.snackbar_text` in place of `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`.

Comment: Didn't help, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[SDK Platform icon location in Top Right of android studio 4.1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oKvU.png) click on this icon and open SDK Platform check whether the version you are working on is downloaded or not...

Comment: After updating to 4.1.2 I haven't seen the issue reappear. I just recently did notice that one of my Pie system images need updating, which I did. We'll see if this comes back.